# (EE) config/hal: NewInputDeviceRequest failed (2) while trying to run Xvfb on centos

Tags: centos, selenium

I'm trying to set up a Selenium tests on a CI server (Jenkins). It runs on Centos 5 and has no monitor. For Selenium tests I need a way to run Firefox so I've had Xvfb installed. I'm using selenium-maven-plugin to start the Xvfb.

```
<profile>
    <id>xvfb-selenium</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xvfb</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xvfb</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

It is inside a profile because I want to run it on CI, but development machines don't need that.

Again I use selenium-maven-plugin to run my selenese tests

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>nessos-selenium-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <configuration>
                <browser>*firefox</browser>
                <suite>src/test/resources/test-suite.html</suite>
                <startURL>${selenium.startURL}</startURL>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>selenese</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now when I try to run this, I get this error in Jenkins:

```
message : Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.
Stack trace : 
java.net.BindException: Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.
    at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.start(SeleniumServer.java:410)
```

This doesn't tell me much so I investigated more. In target/selenium/xvfb.log I've got this error:

```
(EE) config/hal: NewInputDeviceRequest failed (2)
(EE) config/hal: NewInputDeviceRequest failed (2)
(EE) config/hal: NewInputDeviceRequest failed (2)
(EE) config/hal: NewInputDeviceRequest failed (2)
(EE) config/hal: NewInputDeviceRequest failed (2)
```

At this point I'm clueless. From maven logs I can see that xvfb goal runs before selenese with this output:

```
Created dir: /home/jenkins/workspace/myBuild/target/selenium
Launching Xvfb
[INFO] Redirecting output to: /home/jenkins/workspace/myBuild/target/selenium/xvfb.log
Waiting for Xvfb...
Xvfb started
```

I've tried following the instructions here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/selenium-maven-plugin/examples/headless-with-xvfb.html

I did the

```
chmod u+s `which Xvfb`
```

thing and the error message changed to:

```
Fatal server error:
 PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server.
        Perhaps you do not have console ownership?
```

At the bottom of the headless-with-xvfb page there were instructions to fix that. I did that also and now I get `(EE) config/hal: NewInputDeviceRequest failed (2)` again.

Does anyone know how I would continue to debug this error? Or does anyone know what that error even means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really embarassing :) It was already working and that error message can be ignored. My final solution is to start xvfb with the plugin in pre-integration-phase, run jUnit tests with WebDriver API in the integration-test phase. Xvfb closes when the maven run is completed